# Multidimensional array print by key

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have an array like this:

```
$games_array = array(

  "game-one-id" => array(
      array("name" => "Game One"),
      array("url" => "game-one-url"),
      array("asd" => "asdfg")
  ),

  "game-two-id" => array(
      array("name" => "Game Two"),
      array("url" => "game-two-url"),
      array("asd" => "asdfg")
  )

);
```

and I want to list all games in `$games_array` and print some of each game's properties, for example its URL.

This is what I came up with, but nothing is printed:

```
foreach ($games_array as $game_id => $game_data) {
  echo '  
    <table><tr>
    <td><a href="http://www.example.com/game/' . $game_data["url"] . '/">' . $game_data["name"] . '</a></td>
    </tr></table>
  ';
}
```

Could someone please help me

Comment: Why is each individual entry in each array wrapped in its own `array(..)`? Just get rid of the superfluous array layer, then it'll work.

Comment: Do you have control over the creation of the array, bacause the current format is not ideal.

Comment: Yes I just came up with that format and thought it's decent. What would be a better format?

Comment: See Enrique's format below, that's how it should be. http://stackoverflow.com/a/25868868/476

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That loop is related to an array like this

```
$games_array = array(

"game-one-id" => array(
    "name" => "Game One",
    "url" => "game-one-url",
    "asd" => "asdfg"
),

"game-two-id" => array(
    "name" => "Game Two",
    "show_compatibility" => "game-two-url",
    "asd" => "asdfg"
)

);
```

Try! :)

Answer (score 0):

With the `$game_array` you are using, you should be using:

```
foreach ($games_array as $game_id => $game_data) {
  echo '  
    <table><tr>
    <td><a href="http://www.example.com/game/' . $game_data[1]["url"] . '/">' . $game_data[0]["name"] . '</a></td>
    </tr></table>
  ';
}
```

The variable `$game_array` should be:

```
$games_array = array(

  "game-one-id" => array(
      "name" => "Game One",
      "url" => "game-one-url",
      "asd" => "asdfg"
  ),

  "game-two-id" => array(
      "name" => "Game Two",
      "show_compatibility" => "game-two-url",
      "asd" => "asdfg"
  )

);
```

If you want to use:

```
foreach ($games_array as $game_id => $game_data) {
  echo '  
    <table><tr>
    <td><a href="http://www.example.com/game/' . $game_data["url"] . '/">' . $game_data["name"] . '</a></td>
    </tr></table>
  ';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this without changing array format.

```
<?php
    $games_array = array(

      "game-one-id" => array(
          array("name" => "Game One"),
          array("url" => "game-one-url"),
          array("asd" => "asdfg")
      ),

      "game-two-id" => array(
          array("name" => "Game Two"),
          array("url" => "game-two-url"),
          array("asd" => "asdfg")
      )

    );
    foreach ($games_array as $game_id => $game_data) {
        //var_dump($game_data);
      echo '  
        <table><tr>
        <td><a href="http://www.example.com/game/' . $game_data[1]["url"] . '/">' . $game_data[0]["name"] . '</a></td>
        </tr></table>
      ';
    }


    ?>
```

Change array format as

```
$games_array = array(

"game-one-id" => array(
    "name" => "Game One",
    "url" => "game-one-url",
    "asd" => "asdfg"
),

"game-two-id" => array(
    "name" => "Game Two",
    "show_compatibility" => "game-two-url",
    "asd" => "asdfg"
)

);
```

Answer (score -1):

It should be like this:

```
foreach ($games_array as $game_id => $game_data) {
   echo '  
    <table><tr>
    <td><a href="http://www.example.com/game/' . $game_data["url"] . '/">' . $game_data[0]["name"] . '</a></td>
    </tr></table>
  ';
}
```

Each array you have specified as a child game-one-id has no key. By default it will be assinged a key starting from 0, and going up by 1 each time. I think you would probably rather do it like this:

```
$games_array = array(

"game-one-id" => array("name" => "Game One","url" => "game-one-url","asd" => "asdfg")
```

);

```
foreach ($games_array as $game_id => $game_data) {
   echo '  
    <table><tr>
    <td><a href="http://www.example.com/game/' . $game_data["url"] . '/">' . $game_data["name"] . ' - ' . $game_data["url"] . '</a></td>
    </tr></table>
  ';
}
```